# Encapsulating multiple WCF services into a class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, class-library

I have one WCF service with multiple endpoints. Each endpoint has it's own configuration.
My problem is that I'm trying to figure out what will be the best.

1 - Add to my MVC application a service reference to each of the endpoints

2 - Create new DLL that will have the references to each of the endpoints and then add in my MVC application a reference only to this DLL.

I could really use your help to figure if there are any downsides to each of the approaches?

---

- **UPDATE**
  i forgot to mention that i have multiple MVC applications and each one uses only one or two of the WCF services.
  to be more accurate, i now have 6 MVC applications and 7 WCF services. each MVC application uses only 2 WCF.
  in the future the number of MVC apps and WCF will grow.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a server reference but just point svcutil to all three at the same time.  It will generate one set of proxies and one configuration.  It also allows you to share data contracts between the services.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I always put my web references and service references in a standalone assembly called SharedServices. That way; multiple assemblies can share the same references and datatypes can be shared among assemblies. Attaching a web reference to an assembly could lead to many projects being dependent on that assembly solely for the web service defintions.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a service agent that is responsible for accessing the services, abstracting away this logic for your MVC application. The service agent would also be the place to implement other logic like caching, if you would ever need it. See http://tinyurl.com/cbcepgl, below under 'service agent' for some demo code.

Comment: i updated my question with further information which gives more details.
i think you solution is right for services that are not WCF, since WCF services already expose only the public methods signatures so i won't need to give another abstract of the methods

Comment: Well, you can have one service agent per WCF service, or one service agent for all WCF services; it's a choice you have to make.